# How to listen on a single child change in react native firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have below code use `once('value')` to retrieve user's contact list by index. Then if someone change `description`, my contact list will not update in real time because it is `once()`. I can't use `on()` because this will cause crazy query leak. So where should I place `on('child_added')` to listen on every single node.

```
    getContacts(userID) {
    var contactList = [];
    this.ref.child('userContacts').child(userID).once('value', (contacts) => {
        contacts.forEach((contact) => {
            this.ref.child('users').child(contact.key()).once('value', (contact) => {
                contactList.push({
                    key: contact.key(),
                    name: contact.val().name,
                    description: contact.val().description,
                    numberOfProduct: contact.val().numberOfProduct
                }); 

                this.setState({
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(contactList)
                });
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive updates for an object, you will have to attach a listener with `on()`.

If you want to prevent attaching multiple listeners to the same user, keep an object where you keep the listener for each user-key you attached. Then before attaching a new user-listener, check if it already exists:

```
var userListenersByKey = {};
this.ref.child('userContacts').child(userID).once('value', (contacts) => {
    contacts.forEach((contact) => {
      if (!userListenersByKey[contact.key()]) {
        userListenersByKey[contact.key()] = this.ref.child('users').child(contact.key()).on('value', (contact) => {
            contactList.push({
                key: contact.key(),
                name: contact.val().name,
                description: contact.val().description,
                numberOfProduct: contact.val().numberOfProduct
            }); 

            this.setState({
                dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(contactList)
            });
        });
      }
    });
})
```

You'll also want to remove these listeners at some point, so it might be better to listen for `child_added` and `child_removed` for `userContacts` and use that to (optionally) add and remove the user-listeners.

Comment: i tried and i still no idea what `userListenersByKey` does. Could you explain it deep for me? Also, i facing another issue, when data changed, my `ListView` create another row instead of modify existing row. I'm not sure is it related to this question. If not, i will open a new question. Thank in advance

Comment: create new row instead of modify existing row issue fixed. I had my [] in wrong place

Comment: I finally, understand what you meant by `!userListenersByKey[contact.key()]`